# ElasticSearch Aggregations Query

Tags: elasticsearch

I already spent way too much time on this.  I have this aggregation that I can't get to work like it should.

I have a ton of documents with a structure like this (I've ommited some of the parts that aren't relevant for this agg):

```
 {
     "url": "THE_URL",
         "url_params": {},
         "title": "Het Nieuwsblad",
     "referrer": null,
     "time": "2015-08-25T08:35:15.729Z",
     "referrerHost": null,
     "timeOnSite": 16,
     "blocks": [{
     "viewTime": 11,
         "click": 0,
         "view": 1,
         "block": "gentenaar__gentenaar-header"
 }, {
     "viewTime": 11,
         "click": 0,
         "view": 1,
         "block": "gentenaar__gentenaar-headline"
 }, {
     "viewTime": 11,
         "click": 0,
         "view": 1,
         "block": "gentenaar__gentenaar-top"
 }, {
     "viewTime": 11,
         "click": 0,
         "view": 1,
         "block": "gentenaar__gentenaar-top-left"
 }, {
     "viewTime": 11,
         "click": 0,
         "view": 1,
         "block": "gentenaar__gentenaar-top-right"
 }, {
     "viewTime": 11,
         "click": 0,
         "view": 1,
         "block": "gentenaar__gentenaar-right"
 }, {
     "viewTime": 11,
         "click": 0,
         "view": 1,
         "block": "gentenaar__gentenaar-sidebar"
 }, {
     "viewTime": 11,
         "click": 0,
         "view": 1,
         "block": "gentenaar__gentenaar-footer"
 }, {
     "viewTime": 11,
         "click": 0,
         "view": 1,
         "block": "news__breaking-news"
 }, {
     "viewTime": 11,
         "click": 1,
         "view": 1,
         "block": "news__breaking-news-1"
 }, {
     "viewTime": 11,
         "click": 0,
         "view": 1,
         "block": "news__breaking-news-2"
 }, {
     "viewTime": 11,
         "click": 0,
         "view": 1,
         "block": "news__breaking-news-3"
 }, {
     "viewTime": 11,
         "click": 0,
         "view": 1,
         "block": "news__breaking-news-4"
 }, {
     "viewTime": 11,
         "click": 0,
         "view": 1,
         "block": "news__breaking-news-5"
 }, {
     "viewTime": 11,
         "click": 0,
         "view": 1,
         "block": "news__breaking-news-6"
 }, {
     "viewTime": 11,
         "click": 0,
         "view": 1,
         "block": "news__breaking-news-7"
 }, {
     "viewTime": 11,
         "click": 0,
         "view": 1,
         "block": "news__breaking-news-sidebar-1"
 }, {
     "viewTime": 11,
         "click": 0,
         "view": 1,
         "block": "news__breaking-news-sidebar-2-left"
 }, {
     "viewTime": 11,
         "click": 0,
         "view": 1,
         "block": "news__breaking-news-sidebar-2-right"
 }, {
     "viewTime": 11,
         "click": 0,
         "view": 1,
         "block": "news__breaking-news-sidebar-3"
 }, {
     "viewTime": 11,
         "click": 0,
         "view": 1,
         "block": "news__breaking-news-footer"
 }, {
     "viewTime": 11,
         "click": 0,
         "view": 1,
         "block": "news__fast-news-headline"
 }, {
     "viewTime": 11,
         "click": 0,
         "view": 1,
         "block": "news__fast-news-head-1"
 }, {
     "viewTime": 11,
         "click": 0,
         "view": 1,
         "block": "news__fast-news-head-2"
 }, {
     "viewTime": 11,
         "click": 0,
         "view": 1,
         "block": "news__fast-news-head-3"
 }, {
     "viewTime": 11,
         "click": 0,
         "view": 1,
         "block": "news__fast-news-head-4"
 }, {
     "viewTime": 11,
         "click": 0,
         "view": 1,
         "block": "news__fast-news-head-5"
 }, {
     "viewTime": 11,
         "click": 0,
         "view": 1,
         "block": "news__fast-news-head-6"
 }, {
     "viewTime": 11,
         "click": 0,
         "view": 1,
         "block": "news__fast-news-1"
 }, {
     "viewTime": 0,
         "click": 0,
         "view": 0,
         "block": "news__fast-news-2-left"
 }, {
     "viewTime": 0,
         "click": 0,
         "view": 0,
         "block": "news__fast-news-2-right"
 }, {
     "viewTime": 0,
         "click": 0,
         "view": 0,
         "block": "news__fast-news-3"
 }, {
     "viewTime": 0,
         "click": 0,
         "view": 0,
         "block": "news__fast-news-4-left"
 }, {
     "viewTime": 0,
         "click": 0,
         "view": 0,
         "block": "news__fast-news-4-right"
 }, {
     "viewTime": 0,
         "click": 0,
         "view": 0,
         "block": "news__fast-news-5"
 }, {
     "viewTime": 0,
         "click": 0,
         "view": 0,
         "block": "news__fast-news-6-left"
 }, {
     "viewTime": 0,
         "click": 0,
         "view": 0,
         "block": "news__fast-news-6-right"
 }, {
     "viewTime": 1,
         "click": 1,
         "view": 1,
         "block": "news__fast-news-right"
 }, {
     "viewTime": 0,
         "click": 0,
         "view": 0,
         "block": "news__fast-news-bottom"
 }, {
     "viewTime": 11,
         "click": 0,
         "view": 1,
         "block": "news__fast-news-sidebar-1"
 }, {
     "viewTime": 11,
         "click": 0,
         "view": 1,
         "block": "news__fast-news-sidebar-2-left"
 }, {
     "viewTime": 11,
         "click": 0,
         "view": 1,
         "block": "news__fast-news-sidebar-2-right"
 }, {
     "viewTime": 11,
         "click": 0,
         "view": 1,
         "block": "news__fast-news-sidebar-3"
 }, {
     "viewTime": 11,
         "click": 0,
         "view": 1,
         "block": "news__fast-news-sidebar-4-left"
 }, {
     "viewTime": 11,
         "click": 0,
         "view": 1,
         "block": "news__fast-news-sidebar-4-right"
 }, {
     "viewTime": 1,
         "click": 0,
         "view": 1,
         "block": "news__fast-news-sidebar-5"
 }, {
     "viewTime": 0,
         "click": 0,
         "view": 0,
         "block": "news__fast-news-sidebar-6-left"
 }, ...],
     "activeAds": [{
     "viewed": 1,
         "clicked": 0,
         "type": "button",
         "width": 317,
         "height": 75,
         "timeViewed": 10
 }, {
     "viewed": 1,
         "clicked": 0,
         "type": "xlleaderboard",
         "width": 990,
         "height": 122,
         "timeViewed": 10
     }, ...]...
 }
```

It's the blocks array that I'm having problems with.  I want to know per block the sum of clicks, views and viewTime.

I'm trying to use this query:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "range": {
                "dt": {
                  "from": "2015-08-25T00:00:00+00:00",
                  "to": "2015-08-26T23:59:59+00:00"
                 }
               }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                 "url": "http://www.nieuwsblad.be/"
              }
             }
           ]
        }
      }
     }
   },
  "aggs": {
    "per_block": {
      "term": {
        "field": "blocks.blocks"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "clicks": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "blocks.click"
           }
         }
      }
     }
   }
}
```

For the activeAds, I'm using nearly identical code but there it's working perfectly:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "range": {
                "dt": {
                  "from": "2015-08-25T00:00:00+00:00",
                  "to": "2015-08-26T23:59:59+00:00"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "terms": {
                "page.page_type": [
                  "home"
                ]
              }
            }
          ],
          "must_not": {
            "term": {
              "activeAds.timeViewed": 0
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "per_ad": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "activeAds.type"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "clicks": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "activeAds.clicked"
           }
        },
         "views": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "activeAds.viewed"
          }
        },
        "total_time_viewed": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "activeAds.timeViewed"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Anyone have any idea on what I'm doing wrong?